# Django REST with gRPC

Tags: python, django, rest, integration, grpc

Has anyone integrated these 2 technologies successfully? I want to expose gRPC using Django REST. Is that possible? If so, are there any good examples out there? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What kind of integration are you looking for? Nothing stops you from creating API endpoints that internally call gRPC.

Comment: That's what I meant by integration. Do you have examples of Django REST endpoints calling gRPC?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you might be looking for the [django-grpc](https://pypi.org/project/django-grpc/) project. From the description:

> Easy way to launch gRPC server with access to Django ORM and other handy staff.
>   gRPC request are much faster that traditional HTTP requests because are not
>   passed through standard middlewares.

Comment: Thanks John. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 7):

There is a gRPC toolkit for Django ([django-grpc-framework](https://github.com/fengsp/django-grpc-framework)) inspired by Django REST framework that helps you do the following things:

- gRPC server with a development mode (auto-reloader, checks) [server](https://djangogrpcframework.readthedocs.io/en/latest/server.html)
- a service class that manages django db connection state [services](https://djangogrpcframework.readthedocs.io/en/latest/services.html)
- a generic service that map closely to your db models [generics](https://djangogrpcframework.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generics.html)
- a simple proto generator based on model [proto generation](https://djangogrpcframework.readthedocs.io/en/latest/protos.html)
- a simple `RPCTestCase` [testing](https://djangogrpcframework.readthedocs.io/en/latest/testing.html)